# mysql innodb: delete takes seconds

Tags: mysql, innodb

i dont know, why delete on innodb table takes about 30 second

tables has 4mil rows

index for ID

index for KID

(thats are only index, no primary, no unique because table is partitioned)
table is partitioned

```
 delete from my_table where id = 'xxx' and kid = 'ds54f5sad6w5' limit 1
```

in slow log is
query time 39 second
lock time 36 second
rows examined 96879

problem is in disk (ssd used)

explain select sql_no_cache * from `my_table`   WHERE `id` = '1663903' AND `kid` = '84d4af871929d2159d7d7399a79bb384'  LIMIT 1

explain writes

```
id select_type table    type        possible_keys key    key_len ref  rows Extra
1  SIMPLE      my_table index_merge id,kid        id,kid 3,98    NULL 1    Using intersect(id,kid); Using where
```

Comment: What is your primary key? Try to delete only by that key.

Comment: please, post keys that are present in your table. Also try `SHOW INDEXES` statement to figure out your keys cardinality.

Comment: You are deleting **any** record? Sure you don't want a `order by`

Comment: Read this http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/48072/why-does-mysql-ignore-the-index-even-on-force-for-this-order-by/48184#48184  why you should always should create a primary or unique index on a innodb table just writed and posted it myself on dba stackexchange

Comment: And you should run EXPLAIN PARTITIONS to see if your query uses partition pruning

Comment: And should you show the table create statement?

Answer (score 0):

Your EXPLAIN shows that your query is using the "index_merge" access `type`.

So it has to search *two* indexes (these are shown in the `keys` field), find the relevant entries, and then find the intersection between the two results.

This may be better than a non-indexed search, but it's usually better to create a single index with two columns, over (id, kid).